# Pressure ratio for isentropic expansion

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

#### Problem

> Nitrogen $(\gamma = 1.4)$ is expanded isentropically. Its temperature changes from $\pu{620 °F}$ to $\pu{60 °F}.$ Find the pressure ratio.

#### Answer

> $p_1/p_2 = 12.91$

#### My approach

$$\pu{620 °F} = (1799/3)~\pu{K}$$
$$\pu{60 °F} = (2597/3)~\pu{K}$$

Using isentropic relation:

$$\frac{T_1}{T_2} = \left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}$$
$$\frac{1799/3}{2597/3} = \left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)^{\frac{1.4-1}{1.4}}$$
$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \left(\frac{1799/3}{2597/3}\right)^{\frac{1.4}{1.4-1}} = 0.2766669$$

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem set possibly wrong?

Comment: Your temperature conversion shows that 620 F = 600 K, and that 60 F = 866 K, which implies 60 F > 620 F. That's not correct, so look there for problems.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by @Todd in the comments, your temperature conversions are incorrect. To convert between °F and K, use the following conversion:

$$\pu{K} = \frac{\pu{°F}-32}{1.8}+273.15$$

If you want, double check your conversion using an online conversion calculator such as [Metric Conversion](http://www.metric-conversions.org/temperature/fahrenheit-to-kelvin.htm).
Then continue your calculations as you have done (I just did and got the correct answer).